Where does the wire that calls for AC connect to a Peco thermostat?
I am replacing an old honeywell T4039 M 1004 thermostat with a Peco TB158-100 line voltage thermostat that was recommended by the HVAC company that services our exterior systems (we live in a condo).
I have 5 wires coming out of the wall for an AC only system (no heat, no common) & a 3 speed fan.
Where does the wire that calls for AC (red in this case) connect to the new Peco thermostat? My guess is to slot 10 (main 1 output) I'm used to there being a "Y" terminal.




It looks like the new thermostat uses line voltage for the fan but low voltage (24VAC) for the heat/cool calls.  Is that consistent with what the existing system is expecting?

Yes, I believe that is correct.
